# Is there a way to improve the performance of the model or an alternative method?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, model-fitting

Data - Monthly Rainfall of a region for the past 20 years.

Objective - To Forecast for the next 2 years.

[image]

I have used a SARIMA model and after plotting it over the actual values, the fitted model does not capture the several high peaks in the data. So is there a way to improve or an alternative that will include those peaks especially the last two high peaks. (I have also tried ets but SARIMA was the better one).

Comment: You can try another algorithm like LSTM, or you could include exogenous data.

Answer (score 0):

The model is good overall, but does not capture abrupt changes in the time series.
To try and improve your model you can:

- Use [Facebook Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/).
- Create an ensemble of time-series models (Exponential smoothing, ARIMA, Theta model, seasonal Naive), as the [Google developers have done](https://perma.cc/6M7J-MWDY).
- Split the data in smaller geographical regions, predict each of the precipitations and [reconcile the forecasts](https://otexts.com/fpp2/hierarchical.html).
- Perform bootstrap aggregation with [moving block bootstrap](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2021/01/13/moving-block-bootstrap-sas.html). This allows you to get both a measure of central tendency and a prediction interval.
- Consider whether there is a 10 year cycle that you can take account of, since the two outliers occur 10 years apart. Beware that this might overfit to the training data.

Feel free to share your data and I can try out some solutions.

Comment: https://github.com/noob-mun/Data/blob/main/Precipitation%20Data%20(PKD).xlsx is the data. It will be of great help as I am new to time series forecasting and not aware of these methods or how to carry them out but very eager to learn.